# Auto-py-to-exe создает exe файл, который не импортирует библиотеки

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

После конвертации в .exe получаю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал устанавливать через pyinstaller с флагом --hidden-import=urllib3, но результат такой-же

Comment: так вам же пишет pytube, при чём тут urllib3?  - -hidden-import=pytube

Answer (score 0):

попробуй такой аргумент `--collect-submodules "<название модуля>"`